# Guidance on selecting locals for waste treatment installation

Tags: facility-location

I am seeking guidance for a study in which I have the coordinates of 3 wastewater treatment plants (WTPs) shown in blue, and 54 farms shown in red (see the figure below). My goal is to calculate potential locations for the installation of waste treatment centers, taking into consideration the distances between the WTPs and farms. The main idea is to send sludge to these centers and, subsequently, produce fertilizer in these locations and deliver it to the farms. Therefore, these locations need to be strategically positioned to meet the needs of both the WTPs and the farms.

[image: Map 1]

I have calculated the average distances between the WTPs and the farms and obtained the following result:

```
> distance_mean
[1] 19.18519 20.96296 20.12963
```

The mean of the average distances is:

```
> mean(distance_mean)
[1] 20.09259
```

My initial approach was to create random points on the map, taking into account the average distance between the WTPs and farms, which in this case is 20 km. This led to the identification of 5 potential installation sites, indicated in green on the figure.

[image: Map 2]

I am looking for additional suggestions or alternatives to determine these locations based on distance. Any ideas?

*Note:* To calculate the distances, I have the geographical coordinates of each location, and I used the `distm` function in R. To generate maps and random points, I used `QGIS`.

Comment: Search for *multisource Weber problem*.

Comment: @Carlo Soares, I am unsure to understand the difference between the blue location and the green location. Do you want to establish new WTPs besides the existing ones? Or the problem is to find the location of new WPTs apart from the existing ones?

Comment: Thank for reply @A.Omidi. So, the blue locations are wastewater treatment plants (WTPs), and the green ones are potential sites for waste processing centers. The idea is to send sludge to these centers and, subsequently, produce fertilizer in these locations and deliver it to the farms. Therefore, these locations need to be strategically positioned to meet the needs of both the WTPs and the farms. That's why my initial approach was to use the average distance between the WTPs and the farms.

Comment: @RobPratt, thanks for reply.  Can you provide me with any document that explains this in more detail?

Comment: @CarloSoares, I think what you are looking for is very similar to [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/is-there-a-name-for-this-problem/10892#10892) problem. Do you see that?

Comment: Also, another approach is to use clustering to determine which demand points, the reds, would be linked into which one of the green points, clusters. Then in the next step, you can link these clusters with the blue points.

Comment: Thanks @A.Omidi for the answers. I believe it may be similar to the problem you mentioned. How could I solve it for mine? If you need additional information, please let me know. Regarding the clustering approach, I also thought about it, but, for example, if I use K-means, I need to define a specific number of clusters, and I don't want to do that. I want to determine the number of potential locations for waste treatment center installation without specifying a specific number, you know?!

Comment: @CarloSoares, you'r welcome. You can start with one of the mentioned models and see how the problem behaves w.r.t your data. Then modify that, if the results need some tweaks. Also, you can take the number of potential points, greens, as a decision variable with an appropriate cost in the objective function.

Comment: @CarloSoares If you do not have a specific number of WPCs in mind or a specific finite set of possible WPCs, and you do not take into account cost of building/running WPCs, then the answer is to put a WPC in everyone's backyard. So you need to define a criterion function (a cost to minimize, a distance measure to minimize), and if it does not penalize gratuitous creation of WPCs then you also need to add a constraint on how many WPCs to build.